# Returning the product of numbers betweeen max and min in list, and simplify the loop

Tags: python

I have some array elements which were separated by a space,
for ex: `-7 5 -1 3 9`, `3 14 -9 4 -5 1 -12 4`, `-5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -3`.
The task was to find the product of numbers which are located between maximum and minimum of them. And I made something to calculate it

```
n = "-7 5 -1 3 9" 
t = [int(i) for i in n.split()]       # transform to list

if t.index(max(t)) < t.index(min(t)): # loop to cut numbers which are not                                     
    for i in range(len(t)):             # between our max and min numberes in list
        if t.index(max(t)) > i:
            t.pop(i)    
    for i in range(len(t)): 
        if t.index(min(t)) < i:
            t.pop(i)
elif t.index(min(t)) < t.index(max(t)):
    for  i in range(len(t)):            
        if t.index(min(t)) > i:
            t.pop(i)
    for i in range(len(t)): 
        if t.index(max(t)) < i:
            t.pop(i)
t.pop(t.index(min(t)))
t.pop(t.index(max(t)))

def product(list):                   # fuction to return product of a list
    p = 1
    for i in list:
        p *= i
    return p

print(product(t))                   # and print it
```

It looks a little cumbersome, and I have similar problem, is there any way to simplify that loop. Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Since this is already a working solution, I would suggest considering posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, since that's where a question like this belongs. Stack Overflow is meant for troubleshooting help. Good luck!

Comment: your code will fail if there are duplicate entries for min and max.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using NumPy, you can solve the problem in literally two lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
n="-5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -3"
t = [int(i) for i in n.split()]

t = np.array(t) # Convert the list to a numpy array
t[t.argmin() : t.argmax() + 1].prod() # Get the range and the product
```

If you have more than one max element and want to go as far as the right-most of them, the code can be modified accordingly:

```
t[t.argmin() : t.size - t[::-1].argmax()].prod()
```

Comment: Nice to note that numpy is also generally going to be faster than a raw python solution, since it's offloading most of the work to pre-compiled libraries written in C++

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
n = "-7 5 -1 3 9"
n_list = n.split(" ")
n_list = list(map(int, n_list)) #In case of python3 use -- n_list = map(int, n_list)
max = max(n_list)
min = min(n_list)

result = 1
for i in range(len(n_list)):
  if n_list[i] > min and n_list[i] < max:
    result = result * n_list[i]

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a generator, which takes one argument, an iterable and yields values that are within range of `min`, `max` of this iterable. The product is computed as usual:

```
from itertools import chain

def values(iterable):
    lst = list(int(i) for i in chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in n))
    _min, _max = min(lst), max(lst)
    for i in lst:
        if _min < i < _max:
            yield i

n = ['7 5 -1 3 9', '3 14 -9 4 -5 1 -12 4', '-5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 -3']

p = 1
for i in values(n):
    p *= i

print(p)
```

Output:

```
-1234517760000
```